Get aggregate value per group in addition to all detail rows
Suppose I have the following data:



SERVER
COMPONENT
STATUS




A
C1
OK


A
C2
OK


B
C1
OK


B
C2
ERROR



I would like to have a SELECT statement that outputs the detail records and a "subtotal" per Server, with an aggregated value of the STATUS column (If at least one of the values is ERROR, it should read ERROR).
Since only OK and ERROR occur there, MIN() would work here.
Something like this:



SERVER
COMPONENT
STATUS




A
C1
OK


A
C2
OK


A

OK


B
C1
OK


B
C2
ERROR


B

ERROR



I thought that this might be possible with rollup or grouping sets, but I'm at war with these functions ;-)
The following SELECT can be used as a start. ;-)
WITH
   t
   AS
      (SELECT 'A' AS server, 'C1' AS component, 'OK' AS status FROM DUAL
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'A', 'C2', 'OK' FROM DUAL
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'B', 'C1', 'OK' FROM DUAL
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'B', 'C2', 'ERROR' FROM DUAL)
SELECT t.*
  FROM t;


Use ROLLUP:
SELECT server,
       component,
       MIN(status) AS status
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY ROLLUP(server, component)
HAVING GROUPING_ID(server) = 0
ORDER BY server, component

or:
SELECT server,
       component,
       MIN(status) AS status
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY ROLLUP(server, component)
HAVING GROUPING_ID(server, component) < 3
ORDER BY server, component

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (server, component, status) AS
  SELECT 'A', 'C1', 'OK'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', 'C2', 'OK'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', 'C1', 'OK'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', 'C2', 'ERROR' FROM DUAL;

Both output:



SERVER
COMPONENT
STATUS




A
C1
OK


A
C2
OK


A
null
OK


B
C1
OK


B
C2
ERROR


B
null
ERROR



fiddle
